# Why do Process ID's come in the tens of thousands?

Tags: linux, process

Whenever you write a program that prints its own process ID, I've always (without any exception) received numbers ranging in the tens of thousands. Never less, never higher.

I was just wondering, why is are the process ID #s so high? Are the ones below it all system-related processes?

And then when I run the program again, it prints out an ID that is several hundred above the previous execution... what happens between these two executions that come right after each other?

Comment: What operating systems are you asking about? I see many process IDs less than 1,000 on my Linux system, and all are under 10,000 on my Windows system.

Comment: @David: Windows reuses pids.

Comment: Is there a certain algorithm that governs the reuse of pids? I'm assuming this also means there is a maximum number of processes than can be run...

Comment: @Paul: And so does Linux.

Comment: @Dark: On Linux, PIDs wrap around at 32768 by default (adjustable through /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max, I think you can have full 4294967296 if you want)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what happens between these two executions that come right after each other?

Several hundred other processes get run.

You are not the only user.